# How to highlight around of current line in Vim?

Tags: highlight

I want to highlight around of current line in Vim like VSCode.

[image]

**Edit**: I want to highlight up, left, down, and right of current line.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you please elaborate on what you want to accomplish? Perhaps an example of what you'd like to see? A screenshot of VSCode displaying the behavior you would like to have? As it stands, your question is not completely clear as to what you'd like to accomplish... Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, if you want to highlight the cursor line, you should give a look at `:h cursorline`. For "around" the cursor line though, it will require some scripting..

Comment: It's the second very unclear question you ask on the same topic (cf [this closed question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/29261/1841)) you should really take the time to write a complete question explaining what you are trying to do, what you have tried so far and what is blocking you. This is the only way you will get a useful answer.

Comment: I'm really sorry about this very unclear question. I edited this question.

Comment: I think you are asking how to draw a thin line between the current line and the line above it, as well as the current line and the line below it.  I don't think this is possible.  As zorzi and GH1995 point out, only changing the colour of the current line (`:h cursorline`) is possible in vim.

Answer (score 6):

You might try just `:set cursorline`—

```
            *'cursorline'* *'cul'* *'nocursorline'* *'nocul'*
'cursorline' 'cul'  boolean (default off)
            local to window
            {not available when compiled without the |+syntax|
            feature}
    Highlight the text line of the cursor with CursorLine |hl-CursorLine|.
    Useful to easily spot the cursor.  Will make screen redrawing slower.
    When Visual mode is active the highlighting isn't used to make it
    easier to see the selected text.
```

Also see `cursorlineopt`.

To get something more like your screenshot, you can `:highlight CursorLine` and set, e.g., `ctermbg` and `guibg` to soft-gray values (60 and 424450 work for me).

Answer (score 2):

[Conoline.vim](https://github.com/miyakogi/conoline.vim)
This plugin highlights the line of the cursor, only in the current window. The colors change according to the mode (normal/insert). Colors in each mode are independently customizable.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!